# How to get a row array from a table knowing the row index using vba?

Tags: arrays, vba, row, z-index

I was trying to get a row array from table using that : Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table Name").Rows(index).value but I was getting the  error 91

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Dim MyArray As Variant 
myArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("TableName").ListRows(index).Range.Value
```